# How to get "How many unread notifications does user have" on getStream?

Tags: getstream-io

How to get `How many unread notifications does user have` on getStream?

I just need an `integer` value of unread notifications.

(I will call the unread notifications the main like `Facebook` or `Instagram`!)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical response when fetching a Notification feed is:

```
> notificationFeed.get().then((response) => console.log(response));
Promise { _state: 0, _onFulfilled: [], _onRejected: [] }
> { results:
[ { activities: [Array],
   activity_count: 1,
   actor_count: 1,
   created_at: '2017-12-27T10:15:39.215550',
   group: 'e325120c-eaee-11e7-97ec-1283934ff98c',
   id: 'e3267b75-eaee-11e7-8080-800052f2693c.e325120c-eaee-11e7-97ec-1283934ff98c',
   is_read: false,
   is_seen: false,
   updated_at: '2017-12-27T10:15:39.215550',
   verb: 'post' } ],
  next: '',
  duration: '12.76ms',
  unseen: 1,
  unread: 1 }
```

The `unseen` and `unread` properties on the response indicate the number of activities in the notification feed that are marked unseen, and unread respectively.

Comment: Should we retrieve all notification feed? So there is no other way to track the number of notification?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You may store / cache the notification seen/read counts in your backend. At this point in time there is no way to batch/bulk retrieve the seen and read count from multiple feeds. That seems an atypical use case since most commonly a user will only need to access a single Notification feed.